# After apply mAuth.SignOut() in Firebase the documentReference.addSnapshotListener() throw error of null object reference

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-functions

When the user makes `SignOut` automatically I got this error of `null object reference`:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.registration.MainActivity$2.onEvent(MainActivity.java:85)
        at com.example.registration.MainActivity$2.onEvent(MainActivity.java:82)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.lambda$addSnapshotListenerInternal$2(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.2:544)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference$$Lambda$3.onEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.2)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.ExecutorEventListener.lambda$onEvent$0(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.2:42)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.ExecutorEventListener$$Lambda$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.2)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
```

The error is on `MainActivity.java:85` and `(MainActivity.java:82)` what I have on there is this:

```
  DocumentReference documentReference = fStore.collection("Users").document(idUser);
        documentReference.addSnapshotListener(this, new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                userName.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("username"));
                userPhone.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("phone"));
            }
        });
```

The error is happening after the user makes SignOut:

```
btnSignOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //SigOut:
            mAuth.signOut();
            //Send the user to LoginActivity
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, loginActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            
        }
    });
```

my references on the onCreate method are:

```
 mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
 fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
```

Above the onCreate method i have:

```
FirebaseAuth mAuth;
FirebaseFirestore fStore;
```

[image]

in the `onCreate()` method I also have:

```
 mAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
                    Log.d("ERROR", "SEND USER TO LOGIN.");
                        Intent intentLogin = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), loginActivity.class);
                        intentLogin.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(intentLogin);
                }

            }
        };
```

I don't know why I'm getting this error after the apply  mAuth.signOut(); after this happend I'm sending the user to the `loginActivity`. Probably is because the `documentReference.addSnapshotListener` has the method `onEvent` this being triggering after any change 'I'm supposing' I need to prevent this error..

thanks in advance.

Comment: Try adding if(documentSnapshot == null || firebaseAuth.getCurentUser == null) return;
before setting the text on your text fields

Comment: Thanks @GarrenFitzenreiter it works, but why no only add ` if(documentSnapshot !=null){ ..}` is most secure check the current user?

Comment: Last question sir, you know why when I try to register and user `mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)...` it is delaying 5 minutes to create the user? has this ever happened to you? my Internet connection is ok, yesterday there was not problems but today to create an user it delays 5 minutes and sometimes 2 minutes.

Comment: You can add whatever null checks you think are necessary as long as it works. As far as registration taking a long time, I'm not quite sure. Trying checking the status of firebase services and make sure you set your network type to Full on your emulator.

Comment: ok sir. thanks so much.